# Value picked from a combobox isn't getting updated to another wire adapter unless I select another value from the combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-wire-getlistui

I have a combobox populated with listviews from an object. If I select a listview, those records have to be shown in the table. But the records of a selected object are not being updated unless I select another listview. Then the previous selected values are being shown. If I want the values of second time selected listview I need to click again the first listview or another listview. Only then the second listview records are being shown.

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track,api} from 'lwc';
import { getListUi} from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import PRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Product2';

export default class ShowListView extends LightningElement {

@track allListViews;
@track Value;   

@wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT})
wiredlistView({error,data}) {
    if(data){
        this.allListViews = data.lists;
        var listViewData = [];
    for(var i=0;i<this.allListViews.length;i++){
        listViewData.push({"label" : this.allListViews[i].label, "value" : 
this.allListViews[i].apiName});
    }
    this.allListViews = listViewData;
    }else if(error){
        console.log('An error has occurred:');
        console.log(error);
    }
}

@wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT,listViewApiName: '$Value'})
lastView({error,data}){
    if (data) {
        this.sobjectResult = data.records.records;  
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
handleChange(event) {
    this.Value=event.detail.value;     
}
}
```

How do I achieve this?

```
<template>
<lightning-card title=" List View Example" icon-name="standard:action_list_component">
    <lightning-combobox
        name=""
        label="Picklist Value"
        value={Value}
        placeholder="Select a ListView"
        options={allListViews}
        onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-combobox>
    <p>Selected Value is: {Value}</p>
    
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th >
                    <div >Price Book</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div >Product Name</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div>Product Code</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div>Product Family</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template if:true={sobjectResult}>
                <template for:each={sobjectResult} for:item="so">
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={so.id}>
                        <td >{so.id}</td>
                        <td > {so.fields.Name.value}</td>
                        <td > {so.fields.ProductCode.value}</td>
                        <td > {so.fields.Family.value}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template>
            <template if:false={sobjectResult}>
                List View is not contains any data
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</lightning-card>
```

This is the template

Comment: Maybe a problem with your template. I tested your code and it seems working for me. can you share your template code?

Comment: @Klecool. Updated in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not declare the `sobjectResult` in your js and that was the cause of unexpected behavior. You just need to add it to your js.
Also, note since the Spring '20 Release, the `@track` decorator is no longer required.

```
export default class ShowListView extends LightningElement {

@track allListViews;
@track Value;
sobjectResult;
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working perfectly

Comment: You 're welcome!